# FluentAssertions: ShouldBeEquivalentTo vs Should().Be() vs Should().BeEquivalentTo()?

Tags: c#, comparison, fluent-assertions

Can anybody summarize differences and usage scope between them?

I read SO articles,

- [ShouldBeEquivalientTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257861/shouldbeequivalentto-failing-for-equivalent-objects-when-the-subject-is-a-dateti#comment30330255_20257861): ShouldBeEquivalentTo() is intended to be used for comparing complex object graphs rather than the primitive types part of the .NET framework.
- [Should().BeEquivalentTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154559/361100): individual items Equals() implementation to verify equivalence and has been around since version 1. The newer ShouldBeEquivalenTo() introduced in FA 2.0 is doing an in-depth structural comparison and also reporting on any differences.
- Should().Be(): *cannot find.*

In my humble understanding, `ShouldBeEquivalientTo()` and `Should().BeEquivalentTo()` work similar if `Should().BeEquivalentTo()` does in-depth comparison.

Comment: For string comparison ShouldBeEquivalentTo means case-insensitive match

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I agree this is confusing. `Should().BeEquivalentTo()` should actually be called `Should().EqualInAnyOrder()` or something like that. As you said, it uses the `Equals` implementation of the involved objects to see if all of the ones in the `expected` collection appear in the `actual` collection, regardless of order. I'll need to fix that for the next major version.

Comment: Thanks. and how about `Should().Be()`? does it work similar or totally equivalent to one of them?

Comment: There's only `Should().Equal()` which does the same as `Should().BeEquivalentTo()` but requires strict ordering. That's why I was suggesting to rename `BeEquivalentTo` to `EqualInAnyOrder`.

Comment: This been addressed in 5.0. Read all about it at http://www.continuousimprover.com/2018/02/fluent-assertions-50-best-unit-test.html